# I cant seem to figure out the issue with my GUI, the X and Y coordinates are a bit off, with my height and width input off as well

Tags: java

This is my GUI when executed

[image: This is my GUI when executed]

This is what it should look like

[image: This is what it should look like]

when I input values within the text fields, it seems it is not compiling correctly. Either the fields are switched, or my GUI is not set up correctly. Can someone help me? I am a beginner at coding currently.

Project main code

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Project1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {



    public Project1() {
        initComponents();
    }



    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

    private void initComponents() {

        jLayeredPane1 = new javax.swing.JLayeredPane();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        jComboBox2 = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        jComboBox3 = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField4 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Shape Drawing"));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 200, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 200, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Rectangle", "oval" }));
        jComboBox1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jComboBox1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }

            private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }
        });

        jComboBox2.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Hollow", "Solid" }));
        jComboBox2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jComboBox2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }

            private void jComboBox2ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }
        });

        jComboBox3.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Black", "Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Magenta" }));

        jTextField1.setText("100");
        jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }

            private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }
        });

        jTextField2.setText("120");

        jTextField3.setText("X");

        jTextField4.setText("Y");

        jButton1.setText("Draw");
        jButton1.addActionListener((java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) -> {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        });

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 10)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("Shape Type");

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 10)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setText("Fill Type");

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 10)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setText("Color");

        jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 10)); // NOI18N
        jLabel4.setText("x coordinates");

        jLabel5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 10)); // NOI18N
        jLabel5.setText("y coordinates");

        jLabel6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 10)); // NOI18N
        jLabel6.setText("Width");

        jLabel7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 10)); // NOI18N
        jLabel7.setText("Height");

        jLayeredPane1.setLayer(jPanel1, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
        jLayeredPane1.setLayer(jComboBox1, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
        jLayeredPane1.setLayer(jComboBox2, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
        jLayeredPane1.setLayer(jComboBox3, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
        jLayeredPane1.setLayer(jTextField1, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
        jLayeredPane1.setLayer(jTextField2, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
        jLayeredPane1.setLayer(jTextField3, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
        jLayeredPane1.setLayer(jTextField4, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
        jLayeredPane1.setLayer(jButton1, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
        jLayeredPane1.setLayer(jLabel1, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
        jLayeredPane1.setLayer(jLabel2, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
        jLayeredPane1.setLayer(jLabel3, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
        jLayeredPane1.setLayer(jLabel4, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
        jLayeredPane1.setLayer(jLabel5, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
        jLayeredPane1.setLayer(jLabel6, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
        jLayeredPane1.setLayer(jLabel7, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jLayeredPane1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jLayeredPane1);
        jLayeredPane1.setLayout(jLayeredPane1Layout);
        jLayeredPane1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jLayeredPane1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jLayeredPane1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jLayeredPane1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jLayeredPane1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 83, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jTextField4))
                    .addGroup(jLayeredPane1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 83, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jComboBox1, 0, 141, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(jLayeredPane1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 83, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jComboBox2, 0, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(jLayeredPane1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 83, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jComboBox3, 0, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(jLayeredPane1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 83, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jTextField1))
                    .addGroup(jLayeredPane1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 83, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jTextField2))
                    .addGroup(jLayeredPane1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 83, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jTextField3)))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(jLayeredPane1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(224, 224, 224)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jLayeredPane1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jLayeredPane1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jLayeredPane1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(34, 34, 34)
                .addGroup(jLayeredPane1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addGroup(jLayeredPane1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(jLayeredPane1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(jLayeredPane1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2)
                            .addComponent(jComboBox2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(9, 9, 9)
                        .addGroup(jLayeredPane1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jComboBox3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(jLayeredPane1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel4))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(jLayeredPane1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel5))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(jLayeredPane1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel6))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(jLayeredPane1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel7)))
                    .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 20, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jLayeredPane1)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jLayeredPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                                                


    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   

        int w = 0, h = 0, x = 0, y = 0;
        try {
            x = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
            y = Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());
            w = Integer.parseInt(jTextField3.getText());
            h = Integer.parseInt(jTextField4.getText());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter numbers in the field", "Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            return;
        }
        Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(w, h, x, y);
        String strco = jComboBox3.getSelectedItem().toString().toLowerCase();


        Color color;
        try {
            Field field = Color.class.getField(strco);
            color = (Color) field.get(null);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e) {
            color = null; 
        }



        boolean fill = true;


        if (jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Hollow")) {
            fill = false;
        }


        if (jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Rectangle")) {


            Rectangular re = new Rectangular(rec, color, fill);
            painting(re);


        } else {


            Oval ov = new Oval(rec, color, fill);
            painting(ov);
        }




    }                                        


    public void painting(Shape shp) {


        try {
            Drawing d = new Drawing();
            d.setSize(d.getPreferredSize());
            d.drawShape(shp);
            jPanel1.removeAll();
            jPanel1.add(d);
            jPanel1.repaint();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The shape it out of the panel", "Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }


    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Project1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            new Project1().setVisible(true);
        });
    }


// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> jComboBox1;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> jComboBox2;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> jComboBox3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    private javax.swing.JLayeredPane jLayeredPane1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField4;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

drawing code

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Drawing extends JPanel {


    private Shape shape;


    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics grphcs) {
        shape.Draw(grphcs);
        grphcs.drawString("" + shape.getNoOfShapes(), 30, 30);
    }


    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        Dimension dmnsn = new Dimension(200, 200);


        return dmnsn;
        //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }


    public void drawShape(Shape shape) throws Exception {


        if (contains(shape.x, shape.y) && contains(shape.x, shape.y + shape.height)
                && contains(shape.x + shape.width, shape.y) && contains(shape.x + shape.width, shape.y + shape.height)) {
            this.shape = shape;


            repaint();
        } else {
            throw new OutsideBounds(111);
        }
    }
```

shape code

```
package javafxapplication17;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public abstract class Shape extends Rectangle {

  private final Color color;
  private final boolean solid;
  private static int count_shapes;

  public Shape(Rectangle rctngl, Color color, boolean solid) {

    this.color = color;
    this.solid = solid;
    this.setRect(rctngl.width, rctngl.height, rctngl.x, rctngl.y);
    count_shapes++;
  }

  public void setColor(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(this.color);
  }

  public boolean getSolid() {
    return this.solid;
  }

  public int getNoOfShapes() {
    return count_shapes;
  }

  abstract void Draw(Graphics g);

}
```

oval class

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class Oval extends Shape {

  public Oval(Rectangle rctngl, Color color, boolean solid) {
    super(rctngl, color, solid);
  }


  @Override
  void Draw(Graphics g) {
    setColor(g);
    if (getSolid()) {
      g.fillOval(this.width, this.height, this.x, this.y);
    } else {
      g.drawOval(this.width, this.height, this.x, this.y);
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be in this line:

```java
        Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(w, h, x, y);
```

The [documentation for the `Rectangle` constructor you are using](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Rectangle.html#%3Cinit%3E(int,int,int,int)) says that the parameters are in the order `x`, `y`, `width`, `height`, but you have swapped around width and height with x and y.

Try replacing it with

```java
        Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(x, y, w, h);
```